# C# Extension Method Not Defined

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, extension-methods

I have a really basic extension method:

```
namespace PHPImport
{
    public static class StringExtensionMethods
    {
        public static bool IsNullEmptyOrWhiteSpace(this string theString)
        {
            string trimmed = theString.Trim();

            if (trimmed == "\0")
                return true;

            if (theString != null)
            {
                foreach (char c in theString)
                {
                    if (Char.IsWhiteSpace(c) == false)
                        return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use this in the same project (separate .cs file), in the same namespace, and I'm getting a `'string' does not contain a definition for 'IsNullEmptyOrWhiteSpace'` error.

```
namespace PHPImport
{
    class AClassName: AnInterface
    {
        private void SomeMethod()
        {
             if (string.IsNullEmptyOrWhiteSpace(aStringObject)) { ... }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried rebuilding/cleaning the solution, and restarting visual studio to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: You are adding an extension to an instance of a string, so try calling it on the instance: `aStringObject.IsNullEmptyOrWhiteSpace()`

Comment: If you want to use it as static method you don't need to make it an extension. Then call it via class: `StringExtensionMethods.IsNullEmptyOrWhiteSpace("ABC")`.

Comment: Note that this is method is essentially identical to `string.IsNullOrWhitespace`.

Comment: Unfortunately p.s.w.g, IsNullOrWhitespace() returns false when supplying it only with the null terminator '\0'

Comment: A string consisting of a null terminator is neither empty nor whitespace. It will consist of a null terminator followed (internally) by _another_ null terminator.  You don't need to explicitly add a null terminator in C#

Comment: In my case, I need these strings treated as empty.  We pull them from a CSV file, and the null terminator is explicitly placed into empty areas (unfortunately we don't have control over that incoming data). :/

Comment: To be clear, I think the better solution would be to run a IsNullOrWhiteSpace() || IsNullTerminator() check, but the extension method suits us in our time constraints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you made this an extension method, you need to call it as:

```
if (aStringObject.IsNullEmptyOrWhiteSpace())
```

It "extends" usage onto string *instances*, it doesn't add new static methods to the `String` class, which would be suggested by your current call syntax.

Comment: Doh, I knew I was missing something very basic.  Thank you.